# Copy Values Between Tables on Cell Change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy values from one row of a table on the first sheet when the value in that row under column "Called" is changed to "Y" to another table on a different sheet. The columns do not match between each table, so I need to define which column goes where in the other table. I want to make a new row in the 2nd table to paste into and only copy values from the row that had its value changed to "Y". This is my simplest code to convey what I'm doing, but I have tried many things, including an array.
"Table1" is on the first sheet, "Master", Table2 is on the second sheet, "Called List".

EDIT: This is my new code, it succeeds in copying the values to the correct columns on "Table2", but it copies all rows instead of just the current row where "Called" is changed to "Y". Is there a way to copy to a new row on "Table2" only the row in "Table1" where "Y" is being inserted?

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop


Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim NewRow As ListRow

Set KeyCells = Range("Table1[Called]")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then


     If Target.Value = "Y" Then

        Set NewRow = Worksheets("Called List").ListObjects("Table2").ListRows.Add '(AlwaysInsert:=True)

        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[Lessor]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Lessor]").Value
        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[Phone]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Phone Number]").Value
        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[Address]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Address]").Value
        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[Sec]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Sec]").Value
        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[Twn]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Twn]").Value
        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[Rng]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Rng]").Value
        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[County]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[County]").Value
        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[Legal Desc]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Tract]").Value
        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[Gross Acres]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Gross Acres]").Value
        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[Assumed NMA]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Assumed NMA]").Value
        Worksheets("Called List").Range("Table2[Comments]").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Notes]").Value

    End If
 End If


Application.EnableEvents = True
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem or error message with your current code?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to accomplish with `If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range("Table1[Called]")) Is Nothing`. Didn't you set `KeyCells` to that specific table? Shouldn't you check intersect with  the `Target` range?

Comment: There are no errors, it just doesn't run, which is more frustrating than errors because I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: As per my previous comment, from the code you provided, the conditional will never be true because the intersect of `Range("Table1[Called]")` with itself will never be nothing. Perhaps if the table is empty? Again not sure what you are trying to check with that conditional.

Comment: I'm trying to check if a cell under column "Called" is changed to "Y", and if so, then all relevant values from that current row are copied to a new row on "Table2"

Comment: So I need to be able to define that it is pulling from the current row that has the cell changed to "Y" and putting only values from that row into the new row on "Table2"

Comment: So would `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, KeyCells) Is Nothing Then` work?

Comment: This will indeed make it fire when the change is in `Range("Table1[Called]")`. I have concerns with the rest of your code as you never reference what row of the table you are referencing but rather only reference the column header.

Comment: That is also what I was wondering. I'm not sure how to reference the specific row that the change is in so that only the column values in that row copy. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

**" Is there a way to copy to a new row on "Table2" only the row in "Table1" where "Y" is being inserted?"**

1) **"Target.Row"** is your reference row on the master sheet, use it in your "Worksheets("Master").Range("Table1[Notes]").Value" statment

2) **"NewRow"** is your reference row on "called list" sheet, use it in your "Worksheets("Called List")**.Cells(Range("Table2[Lessor]").Value" statement

3) If you convert your **Table?[...]** to named ranges you can use something like:

```
Range("T2_Lessor").Cells(NewRow).Value = Range("T1_Lessor").Cells(KeyCells.Row).Value
```

Ex. of named range:

"Table1[Lessor]" becomes
'T1_Lessor' =OFFSET('Master'!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA('Master'!$B:$B),1)

"Table2[Lessor]" becomes 
'T2_Lessor' =OFFSET('Called List'!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA('Called List'!$B:$B),1)